# My program isn't opening the data from the file. I have no errors. Am I missing something important?

Tags: c++

```
inputFile.open("V:\CmpSci201\Labs\PlayerStats.txt");
cout << "2017 Baseball Stats\n";

if (inputFile)
{
    getline(inputFile, stats);

    while (inputFile >> stats)
    {
// ...
inputFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error Opening the file.\n";
    }
// ...
```

Comment: Please give us enough code to reproduce your issue and an explanation of the errors or behaviour that you see.

Comment: you have to use double backslash `\\\`.

Answer (score 5):

Since backslash is the escape character in C++ strings, you have to use two backslashes to include a literal backslash. So you want `"V:\\CmpSci201\\Labs..."`.